# How to delete "URL Types" from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I did a URL Type but I clicked on the "+" icon again and now I can't delete the others. Maybe I'm stupid but I'm unable to delete them :(
(This option is found under project > Targets > app > Info)

[image]

Comment: I'd like to see the person who is responsible for this feature.
It's very interesting to me what kind of creature added feature with ability to add but not remove in world's most popular official iOS development tool.

Comment: And not only is this STILL A BUG in Xcode 13 but now the Icon field is gone and the area below the standard properties says 'click here to add additional document type properties' but CLICKING DOES NOTHING.

Comment: Why not use GIT and run `git restore App/Configuration/Info.plist`? But I can agree, that this feature is still missing in Xcode 13.3 (March 2022). As this is built in and preloaded by Xcode, you have to close the project in Xcode, restore the file and open the project again.

Comment: It's just ridiculous to be looking for an answer to this still in 2023.

Comment: Still true in Xcode 14.2

Comment: Xcode 15.0 beta 2: same.

also, clearing out the forms fields do not trigger the IDE to prune the `CFBundleURLTypes` key from the `Info.plist`. The plus button unfailingly means: add this to the XML :)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

I found a way to delete them: just open the **Info.plist**, delete the other rows and build/clean the project.

[image]

**EDIT**

You might have to restart XCode to see the changes.

Comment: In my case build/clean was not enough... I also had to restart XCode.....

Comment: I confirm I had to restart XCode also after a clean build

Answer (score 18):

1. Right click on your Info.plist;
2. "Open As" -> "Source Code";
3. Search "CFBundleURLTypes", and delete that you want to delete;
4. Clean and build

[image: I did not have enough reputation to post images.]

Answer (score 5):

Open info.plist in you favorite text editor and delete the nodes.

Comment: And close and reopen the project. :)

Comment: That's true. I cannot find the URLType items in info.plist in xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it by hovering over it and at the top right of the panel for that specific url type, there is a grey square 'X' button.

Comment: Sorry. The button always shows for me at the top right of that panel row of each URL type.

Comment: Oh ok, then it must be an Xcode bug, anyway thanks and I just found that I can delete the entries from the Info.plist haha

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer